# Add a name tag from select to textarea at cursor position in React

Tags: reactjs, textarea

I'am newbie in Reactjs and I have a problem like this picture below[image]

I want when i focus textarea at behind 'Mr' and click $name, the textarea will be like this:
[image]

if someone has done something like this please give me a hint,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using jQuery. Here is my solution.

```
$("#my-select").on("change", function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    var text = $("#my-textarea").val();

    var newText = text + selectedValue;

    $("#my-textarea").val(newText);
});
```